# Parsing JSON data using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to fetch the data for some of the ETF's from Tipranks website using the code below:

```
url = 'https://www.tipranks.com/etf/xle/forecast'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
soup1 = soup.findAll('script')[6].text.strip()
data = json.loads(soup1)
text = data['mainEntity'][4]['acceptedAnswer']['text']
suggestion = text.split('rating of ')[1].split(' which is')[0]
```

I get the error: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Sometimes it works, but this morning it stopped working, and I don't know if it's because I am hammering the server too much or something else.

Comment: Did you do basic debug, by printing `soup1` to see what you get?

Comment: Try `print(r.status_code)`, so it will be clear if the server is blocking you or if there is another reason.

Comment: printing soup1 gives some thing like this (with no error): if (window.__tipranksPlanId__ !== undefined)
       document.body.className += " tr-body-" + window.__tipranksPlanId__;
    var cookieData=getCookie();
    if(cookieData.hadHoldings){
       document.body.className += " tr-body-had_holding"
    }

Comment: print(r.status_code) is 200 so the server is not blocking it. the problem is with the line - data = json.loads(soup1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> printing soup1 gives some thing like this (with no error): `if (window.__tipranksPlanId__`

Okay, so that's not [JSON](https://www.json.org/).

Sounds like the website was updated, and `soup.findAll('script')[6]` is no longer what you expect.